# Mixin size arguments CSS issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application where I have installed following gems -

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sass','3.4.22'
gem "bourbon"
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem "compass-rails"
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'susy'
```

In my application.css.scss

```
*= require style
*= require responsive

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "compass";
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "screen.scss";
@import "mobile.scss";
@import "ie.scss";
@import "print.scss";
```

When I run rails s and hit my URL I get following error:

```
Mixin size takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that Bootstrap and Bourbon both define a `size` [Sass mixin](http://sass-lang.com/guide), with different numbers of arguments.

I have had problems with those two frameworks conflicting in the past. I'm not sure what the current state is, but at that time, it didn't seem like a good idea to use both at the same time.

It might of course be another of the dependencies, like Suzy, that defines a conflicting `size` mixin. You could check the documentation or code for each library and see which define such a mixin.

EDIT:

Yes, this is indeed the case. [In Bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/d607cd6e457b80405991b8516d30e8f788817ed5/app/assets/stylesheets/addons/_size.scss#L32), the mixin takes one argument. [In bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/5d6b2ebba0c2a5885ce2f0e01e9218db3d3b5e47/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_size.scss#L3), a mixin by the same name takes two arguments.

So they don't go together.

Comment: But then how do I use bootstrap ?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to choose one or the other of Bourbon or Bootstrap. They're simply not compatible. Unless you want to edit one of them, renaming mixins so they no longer conflict. It would be nice if these frameworks had some sort of compatibility mode where they use longer names for mixins to avoid conflicts, but I don't think they offer that.

Comment: Raman, please upvote and accept (the check mark) this answer if you feel it answered the question.

Comment: I removed bootstrap-sass from gemfile & removed @import statements for compass, bourbon and the error was resolved.